# Why does Ajax only work for the newest post?

Tags: php, ajax

I want to use Ajax to call a PHP page without refresh.

Here is my code

```
<?php 


global $db;
$cmd = "SELECT * FROM posts order by date desc";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$cmd);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $post_txt = $row['text'];
    $post_image = $row['image'];
    $postid = $row['postid'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    $userid = $row['userid'];

    $new_date=time_elapsed_string($date);


    ?>


    <?php
    global $db;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '$userid'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        $acountname = $row2['name'];
        $acountlast_name = $row2['lastname'];
    } 
    ?>


<?php



echo"
<div id='postShare'>

    <div class='col-xs-7' id='listPost'>
                <div class='list-group'>    

            <input type='hidden' value='$userid' id='user_id_input_hidden'>     
            <li class=list-group-item text-center'><span class='pull-right'><p><a href='profile.php' id='prof_btn'>$acountname  $acountlast_name</a></p></span>&nbsp;
            <span class='pull-left'><p>$new_date</p></span>
            <hr>
            <center><h5 id='show_post_title'>$post_txt</h5></center> <hr>";?>
```

I want to load `profile.php` with Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#prof_btn').click(function(){

        var userid = $('#user_id_input_hidden').val();
        var dataString = 'userid=' + userid;

        $.ajax({

          url:'profile.php',
          type:'POST',
          data:dataString,
          success:function(prof){
            $('html').empty();
            $('html').append(prof);
          }

        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

But it only works for the newest posts in `echo` not for any posts. What is wrong?

Comment: If you want to execute the `echo` command for each result row, you need to put it inside the `while` loop.

Comment: You're overwriting your `$acountname` and `$acountlast_name` each time you loop through your while loop

Comment: I'm confused that you say you're wanting to return all posts, not just the newest, yet your sql statement is only getting profile info. And by the looks of your ajax post with an id, it's no surprise you only get one record. Could you edit your question and clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Additionally, you have a number of undefined variables (`$post_txt` and `$new_date` for example)

Comment: guys im sorry i edited my question the while and echo works but i want to when the user clicked ad the link name #pro_btn  the page named profile.php load with ajax but it only works for newest post not all post

Comment: Just so you know, your HTML has really bad structure. Very bad for SEO.

Answer (score 2):

When you load the profile, the `#prof_btn` element you added the event to are gone, and replaced by new ones that don't have any events bound.

You have two options:

1. Reapply the events manually.
2. Use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to delegate the events to a parent element that *doesn't* get replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Move the echo inside the loop

```
global $db;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '$userid'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    $acountname = $row2['name'];
    $acountlast_name = $row2['lastname'];
    echo"
        <div id='postShare'>
        <div class='col-xs-7' id='listPost'>
        <div class='list-group'>    
        <input type='hidden' value='$userid' id='user_id_input_hidden'>     
        <li class=list-group-item text-center'><span class='pull-right'><p><a href='profile.php' id='prof_btn'>$acountname  $acountlast_name</a></p></span>&nbsp;
        <span class='pull-left'><p>$new_date</p></span>
        <hr>
        <center><h5 id='show_post_title'>$post_txt</h5></center> <hr> 
        ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last bracket here:

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    $acountname = $row2['name'];
    $acountlast_name = $row2['lastname'];
---> }
```

and put in the end here:

```
<center><h5 id='show_post_title'>$post_txt</h5></center> <hr>";
--> }?>
```